# import local library error in java

Tags: java, import, static-libraries

I have the `In` package from [Princeton](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/In.java.html) loaded into the same directory as my files, and I compiled it.

And, I use the package in my code.  But, when I use `import In;` somehow I still get an error?

```
java:7: error: '.' expected
import In;
       ^
```

What is the solution to this silly problem?

Comment: `In` isn't a package, it's a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to fix this problem, you either need to add a package declaration to `In.java` that is the same as your package (and then simply omit your import statement), or (my recommendation) you need to add a package declaration to `In.java` that is different than your package (and move it to the corresponding folder), and then import `In` by the name of the package that you've given it.

To make this more concrete:

1. Add the following to the top of `In.java`:

   ```
   package edu.princeton.cs.introcs.in;
   ```
2. Then move it to the corresponding "edu/princeton/cs/introcs/in" directory. 
   (Create it if it doesn't exist).
3. Then, in your file, import it by its qualified name:

   ```
    import edu.princeton.cs.introcs.in.In;
   ```

Note that, in both of the cases above, you'll need to compile In.java along with your code that uses it (or you need to compile In.java, first, and ensure that it is on the classpath when compiling your code that uses it), and at runtime, you need to bundle In.class with your code (e.g. in the JAR you produce) or similarly guarantee that the byte code for that class (either the .class file or a JAR containing the .class file) are on the class path when executing your compiled code.

Comment: Why do you recommend the second one?  The first one seems so much easier, unless I'm not understanding it correctly...

Comment: I don't have a directory called `edu/princeton/cs/introcs/in`, so I'm not sure where to put the file.  In the past, I've just been putting all of the files I need in the same directory as the files that I wrote myself.  Is  `edu/princeton/cs/introcs/in` arbitrary?  or must it be in that exact path?

Comment: I'm recommending that, because packages are the unit of isolation in Java, and generally only related files should go in the same package. The directory structure must match the package name. All your files should have a package associated with them, and the directories relative to the directory from which you invoke the Java compiler should match the package name.

Comment: Yeah...this works.  It still baffles me that the answer from @paulsm doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The code you linked to *has no package*.

Just delete `import In`, and somewhere in your code create an instance `In myIn = new In(myUrl);`, and you should be good.

Alternatively, modify your copy of "In.java" and make it the same package as you're using for the rest of your code.

Look at the `main()` in the code for examples of how to use class "In".

Comment: I see your point about there being no package - noted.  However, your first suggestion ("Just delete....") still gives me an error with every instance of `In` it says it `cannot find symbol`.

Comment: Also, I already copied `In.java` into the same directory as the rest of my code (and hence the same package as the rest of my code, too), and I added `package <directory-name> ` at the top of every file.  Somehow, an error still results about `cannot find symbol`.